# How can I add header include dirs when installing pip packages?

Tags: python, compiler-errors, pip, environment-variables, mpi

I'm on a cluster on which I have no rights, and I'm trying to `pip install mpi4py`. Since I cannot install the `python3-devel` package, I downloaded it and placed it in `~/.local/`. Regardless of whether this has a chance of succeeding, the following confuses me.

If I simply run `pip3.4 install --user mpi4py`, I am met with this error:

```
/opt/sgi/mpt/mpt-2.14/bin/mpicc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Werror=declaration-after-statement -DNDEBUG -fmessage-length=0 -grecord-gcc-switches -fstack-protector -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -g -DOPENSSL_LOAD_CONF -fPIC -DHAVE_CONFIG_H=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DHAVE_DLOPEN=1 -I~/.local/include/python3.4m/ -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c src/MPI.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/src/MPI.o
In file included from src/MPI.c:4:0:
src/mpi4py.MPI.c:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Python.h"
```

So I guess I would need to inform `pip` about the location of this header. I try to to so with

```
pip3.4 install --user --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I~/.local/include/python3.4m/" mpi4py
```

But I still receive the same error (??). I also tried prefixing `CPATH=$CPATH:~/.local/include/python3.4m` to the command without the global options, but to no avail.

How come `pip` simply ignores the include path?

The server is some kind of Suse Linux Enterprise.

**Update**: I turns out the path must be absolute, but the same problem occurs during the linking stage:

```
ls ~/.local/lib64/
libpython3.4m.so  libpython3.so  pkgconfig
```

So I add `--global-option="-L$HOME/.local/lib64/"` to the `pip` command, and then this:

```
 /opt/sgi/mpt/mpt-2.14/bin/mpicc -pthread _configtest.o -L/home/student/n/name/.local/lib64/ -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4 -lpython3.4m -o _configtest
    /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.4m
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    failure.
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
    error: Cannot link MPI programs. Check your configuration!!!

    ----------------------------------------
```

So the library path is added, the `-l<libname>` matches but it doesn't link. It appears, `libpython3.4m.so` is actually a symlink to `libpython3.4m.so.1.0` which I cannot find. Maybe this is the problem, since my manual installation of `python3-devel` does not install some dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the path passed as a global option must be absolute, so `~` must be replaced by the home directory's full path.

However, a second problem emerged, since `libpython3.4m.so` is actually a symlink and the original is not included in the rpm package `python3-devel`, which I installed manually. It is therefore necessary to obtain `libpython3.4m.so.1.0` form e.g. https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libpython3.4m.so.1.0()(64bit) and place it in the same directory as the link.